# Jekyll: Access attribute of collection?

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages, yaml-front-matter

I'm trying to create a second `_posts` that behaves similar (it can be linked to, it has it's own layout, it's stored within the `_works` folder, and each work is titled with `some-name.md`).

Everything works great, except I can't find how I access the frontmatter attributes of that markdown file... The only variable that works is `{{content}}` but I want to access all the other attributes.

**_config.yml**

```
collections:
  works:
    output: true
```

**layouts/work.html**

```
---
layout: default
---

<div class="work-single">
  <h1>{{ work.title }}</h1> ... doesnt work
  <h2>{{ work.subtitle }}</h2> ... doesnt work

  {{ content }}
</div>
```

**_works/test-product.md**

```
---
layout: work
date: 2018-03-25 01:00:00 +0900
category: illustration
title: A test work product image
subtitle: This is a great product
---

Here is a test of a product which uses **markdown**.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From inside template, the `page` object is available : `{{ page.title }}`, and so on.